# Campy cranks and pedals compatibility

Tags: crankset, compatibility, pedals, vintage, campagnolo

I have a campy Super Record crank set from around the 1970’s stamped with 9/16x20F and campy pedals stamped with 9/16x20, but am met with lots of resistance when I try to install them.

The cranks came with Time clip in pedals which are also stamped with 9/16x20… these go in easily.

Any ideas what could be going on?

Have also tried the campy pedals in a modern crank and they go in fine.

Edit: I had the crank threads chased and chased the pedal threads using an old crankset from a Peugeot. The pedals went in but holey moley they were tight.

Comment: I have encountered this on TA cranks before. You may wish to have the crank threads chased out with the correct taps and try again. But only if your Campag pedals correctly fit other cranks!

Comment: Thanks for your advice Joe, got them in but only just. Hopefully I wont find a reason to have to remove them any time soon!

Comment: Install with plenty of grease so you *can* remove them if you need to.